# Mongo collection name with spring data not set correctly

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to use a base class for my mongo collections and then have the collection name come from the derived classes; however, the collection name is always just `entity` ( instead of, in this case, `Derived`).

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Entity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And derived classes like:

```
// I've also tried @TypeAlias("Derived")
@Document(collection = "Derived")
public class Derived extends Entity {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

With a repository like:

```
@Component
public interface Repository<T extends Entity> extends MongoRepository<T, String> {

    T findById(String id);

}
```

Comment: think you should create repo for Derived class like DerivedRepository extends MongoRepository<Derived , String> .. or you should find in direction of solving mapping colletion name when inheritance case

Answer (score 0):

Follow this working example.
Let's declare a **base document model** from which every document model must inherit

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class BaseDocument {

    @Id
    private BigInteger id;

    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.id == null || obj == null || !(this.getClass().equals(obj.getClass()))) {
            return false;
        }

        BaseDocument that = (BaseDocument) obj;
        return this.id.equals(that.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id == null ? 0 : id.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Just for example, I declare my **Code** model. **Note that collection name, if differs from class name, can be set with @Document annotation**

```java
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

@Document(collection = "codes")
public class Code extends BaseDocument {

    @Field("code")
    private String code;

    @Field("holiday")
    private String holiday;

    public Code(String code, String holiday) {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.holiday = holiday;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getHoliday() {
        return holiday;
    }

    public void setHoliday(String holiday) {
        this.holiday = holiday;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Code [code=" + code + ", holiday=" + holiday + "]";
    }
}
```

At this point you can easily use these classes using MongoOperations and other classes in order to operate on database and collections. MongoOperations has all the methods you need to operate on collections such as: findOne, findAll and so on.
Just to be clear, you can use MongoOperations in the following way:

```java
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), "yourDBname"));
```

I **strongly** suggest to implement a service class which operate on collection, like this one, instead of operating directly on it:

```java
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

public class CodesService extends BaseService implements BaseOperations{

    @Override
    public BaseDocument findOne(Long id) {
         Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("code").is("8"));
        return this.mongoOps.findOne(query, Code.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<? extends BaseDocument> findAll() {
        List<Code> subs = this.mongoOps.findAll(Code.class);
        List<? extends BaseDocument> codes = subs;
        return codes;
    }

}
```

This class implements the following interface:

```java
import java.util.List;

public interface BaseOperations {

    public BaseDocument findOne(Long id);   
    public List<? extends BaseDocument> findAll();  
}
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: But this is a solution without Spring Data Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the `Repository<T extends Entity>` interface like given below

```
public interface SomeInterfaceName extends Repository<Derived>{
}
```

Now try to `@Autowire` the `Repository<Derived>` repo

It will give you the desired output